# Level/Group label system?

Tags: php

I am working on a login system and have a basic admin/level system implemented in to it. Right now the levels are just numbers (1-9). I do however have them labeled as different names or groups. For example, 1=member, 2=Supporter and so on. I also have a member list that displays the user id, level, and time of last activity. However it only shows the number for the id (as to be expected). My question is how would I set it up so the numbers end up displaying the name/group on the member list?
Thanks in Advanced, Josh

Here is the code for the table:

```
<?php 

    include("include/session.php");


function displayUsers(){
   global $database;
   $q = "SELECT username,userlevel,email,timestamp "
       ."FROM ".TBL_USERS." ORDER BY userlevel DESC,username";
   $result = $database->query($q);
   /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
   $num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);
   if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)){
      echo "Error displaying info";
      return;
   }
   if($num_rows == 0){
      echo "Database table empty";
      return;
   }
   /* Display table contents */
   echo "<table align=\"left\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\">\n";
   echo "<tr><td><b>Username</b></td><td><b>Level</b></td><td><b>Last Active</b></td></tr>\n";
   for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
      $uname  = mysql_result($result,$i,"username");
      $ulevel = mysql_result($result,$i,"userlevel");
      $time   = mysql_result($result,$i,"timestamp");

      echo "<tr><td>$uname</td><td>$ulevel</td><td>$time</td></tr>\n";
   }
   echo "</table><br>\n";
}
?>
```

my "array":

```
<?php echo $form->error("upduser"); ?>
<table>
<form action="adminprocess.php" method="POST">
<tr><td>
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="upduser" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $form->value("upduser"); ?>">
</td>
<td>
Level:<br>
<select name="updlevel">
<option value="1">Member
<option value="2">Supporter
<option value="3">Donor
<option value="4">VIP
<option value="5">Veteran
<option value="7">Co-Founder
<option value="8">Founder
<option value="9">Admin
</select>
</td>
```

I just need help setting up an array with the code

Comment: Don't use `mysql_result` as it is deprecated (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php). Also, you will need some kind of mapping (i.e. using an Array), to show text instead of the userlevel.

Comment: I have a... sort of array in the submit field. So ti shows the name, but sets the value Could I use this as an array? See post edits for code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a table in your database with the info for the levels (id and name) then use a join in your query to get the name with the user details.

The other solution, which in my opinion is less advisable, would be to hard-code your array and display the corresponding level name:

```
function displayUsers(){
    $levels = array('1'=>'Member','2'=>'Supporter','3'=>...);
    //do_query
    //loop results
    $ulevel = $levels[mysql_result($result,$i,"userlevel")];
    //continue loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would try to add or edit the database, but when I do it stops working. Really weird I know. I also tried that hard code (which is what I will probably do unfortunately) and it gave me an error when I put it in. The error was:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in

Comment: @s28400 Sorry I mixed my Javascript with my PHP. Updated now. And how does it stop working? how are you manipulating the database?

Comment: ah np, happens all the time xD.. well ow it is giving me this:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in.. And as far as the data base is concerned, I have no idea. I will have to post another question regarding that.

Comment: That's weird, you shouldn't get any syntax errors. Is that on the `$ulevel` line? You did complete the array declaration with all your values right? You can try `$ulevel = mysql_result($result,$i,"userlevel");` `$ulevel = $levels[$ulevel];`

Comment: yes, I filled in the rest of the array, Yes it was the $ulevle line. I tried what you said and it now says:(Fatal error: Cannot re-declare displayUsers() (previously declared in the..) I know why it is saying that, it is doing it because Function displayUsers() was already used (see code above). How would I go about fixing this? Should I add the array to the other function?

Comment: Yes what I posted here is not another function you should add to your code, I was referencing your current function. You just need to add the array declaration to the beginning of your function and replace the line inside the `for` loop where you assign the value to `$ulevel`

Comment: what "for" loop are you referring to? oh nvm found it

Comment: ok coolbeans, I got it working, Thank you so much for your help and time. Sorry it took me so long to digest the code lol.

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear you got it working. Good luck with your project :)